# Auto fill not working correctly in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Good morning, I have a form in a page which contains the following fields:

- Name
- Surname
- Account ID (type Password)
- Password (type Password)

When a user visits this page the Surname and AccountID is being filled automatically (which is wrong). The Surname field is being filled with an old saved username and the AccountID is being filled with an old saved password. **Autocomplete is set to OFF** however this is not working. I do not want a situation where a user visits this page, the two fields mentioned above will be filled automatically. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
    $('input[type="text"]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
}
```